# QGIS layer with enhanced shadow style

Tags: qgis, coding-style

is it possible to enhance the shadow effect to choose the value from the table instead of mm or pixel? maybe in the next version of QGIS.
Or is there any other workaround

Comment: Do you mean the shadow effect for labels? If so, you can use the **Data-defined** option and type the name of your column which contains values for your specific shadow option such as the offset.

Comment: no, only for the layer style.

Comment: Ahh, you are using QGIS 2.10? I do not have this yet but hopefully others can adivse :)

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not currently possible. The only workaround I can think of weight be to have multiple versions of your layer with different shadow radius where each layer is filtered to particular features..